# Android Retrofit ParseSdk Geopoint

Tags: parse-platform, retrofit

I have some place data in parse database.
I would like to use retrofit to find closet place to given lat and longitude
Below is the link , and curl request.

https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#geopoints-geo-queries

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxx" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'limit=10' \
  --data-urlencode 'where={
    "location": {
      "$nearSphere": {
        "__type": "GeoPoint",
        "latitude": 30.0,
        "longitude": -20.0
      }
    }
  }' \
```

How can i convert above curl to retrofit call ?
I think i have to use QueryMap somewhere , but cannot figure out where.
This is what i have so far.

```
@GET("/classes/Place")
void getPlaces(@Query("limit") Integer limit,
               Callback<PlacesResult> callback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is request with headers `"X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxx"`, `"X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxx"` and form url encoded body with `@Query("where")` that takes up string.

You can put these headers in http call `Interceptor` for all requests.

Yes, this can be done with `QueryMap`, which will be of two query params.

Comment: I dont understand  what you mean by two query params. Can you clarify? Where do i fit in location, nearsphere?

Comment: This request needs two query paramaters. One is `limit` which is interger and the other is `where` where you put the `location nearsphere` body payload.